# How to utilize a js minimization for a web site of a big organization

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, minify, yui-compressor

I am looking for a JS minimization (maybe CSS as well) tool to use in our website. The site is fairly big and we cant manually minify files individually. We are also planning to use Long term caching for files and need to append like a version number to each file. I am afraid that this is very hard to keep track of when publishing frequently.

I know of tools like YUI Compressor, etc.. is there, but I am not sure how they are used for a big project like I have. Technically, I am looking for a script or an app that can be called after our development is finished to utilize it with the minified versions of files.

What are the common practices big companies use/follow these days ?? Any help is appreciated. I am just not sure what to search for.

Thank you.

Comment: _"that can be called after our development is finished"_ If you do not do minifying during the dev process, you are going to have a hell of a time afterwards since missing semicolons and such will bite you in the butt. Easy to set up if you have a build system, different flag makes min files to use.

Comment: What framework are you using to build your application? ASP.NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I advise you to use a kind of makefile toolchain (there are many, for example ant or maven) to :

- concatenate your js files in one file
- then minify the resulting files (I use [Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/), called with an ant target)

Note that making one file is the most important operation as on modern networks the latency due to the number of requests is much more a burden than the total size. This way you can easily work with dozens or hundreds of js (or css) files and don't hesitate to make a new one as soon as it helps the code source being readable and maintainable.

And this eliminates the need for the (manual or not) management of visible versionning of files for caching reasons.

As said recently [in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454619/how-to-write-modular-client-side-javascript), to help debug, my deployement scripts always make two versions in parallel : one non concatenated/minified and one concatenated/minified. The uncompressed version enables the development/test onsite without any deployement operation.

Comment: I like the idea of having two version of the code: one for the unminified development code, second for the minified version. I am imagining there are two folders to hold each version respectively. My question is,if there is already such application that kind of automates this process.

It seems that Google Closure Compiler is only for JS, any suggestions for CSS, or even HTML files ??

Comment: I don't know but this is a few lines in a build system and it depends of your build toolchain. You need to have a list of the js files somewhere, at least to give the import order. For css, you have nothing to do apart concatenation.

Comment: Thanks for the help dystroy. Can you explain what are you mean by 'build toolchains' and 'build system' ? I am not familiar with these concepts.

Comment: I mean that when you build or deploy a complex application, you always have a lot of operations to do, like packaging, zipping, concatenating, compiling, etc. You *need* to automate those tasks and there are dedicated tools, like *makefile*, or [ant](http://ant.apache.org/) or Maven and many others that I don't know. Of course you can also do a lot of those tasks using standard shell scripts but it's more painful when it gets complex.

Comment: I want to add that some people do, in fact, minify their CSS. Similar to JS, however, when debugging, line numbers are useless. So, you will likely want some way of viewing the unminified files as well. If you have some sort of staging or QA server, you could set it up so that always serves unminified, uncombined files. I've also worked on projects where you can turn this on/off with a query string (`?..debug..=on`).